# What is the best option on Amazon AWS to run R code in parallel that was designed for a Slurm manager?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, slurm

I currently have R code that can be run through a Slurm manager with a shell and batch script. Essentially, my shell script creates 1000 job arrays, which then calls the batch script 1000 times.

I am wondering how I can take this set-up and what might be the most efficient way to transfer it to Amazon AWS. If not, what is the most effective way in Amazon AWS to run an R script multiple times and to take advantage of as many cores as possible? Is the RStudio Server a good option?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: For RStudio Server, you can ask your question here https://community.rstudio.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

StarCluster may be a good choice:

[StarCluster](http://star.mit.edu/cluster/index.html) is an open source cluster-computing toolkit for Amazon’s Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2)

It is a part of The STAR program at MIT, that seeks to bridge the divide between scientific research and the classroom

You can easily deploy a cluster of any size and comprised of instances of your choice. NFS, MPI and OpenGrid resource manager will work out-of-the-box. You can also install SLURM on the cluster. With single commands you can boot or shutdown the cluster.

Simple commands to create and manage clusters are as [follows](http://star.mit.edu/cluster/docs/latest/overview.html):

> *** Create and Manage Clusters ***
>
> StarCluster allows easily creating one or more clusters of virtual
>   machines in the cloud:
>
> $ starcluster start -s 10 mycluster
>
> Use the listclusters command to keep track of your clusters:
>
> $ starcluster listclusters
>
> Login to the master node of your cluster:
>
> $ starcluster sshmaster mycluster
>
> Add additional nodes to your cluster for more compute power:
>
> $ starcluster addnode mycluster
>
> Remove idle nodes from your cluster to minimize costs:
>
> $ starcluster removenode mycluster node003
>
> When you’re done using the cluster and wish to stop paying for it:
>
> $ starcluster terminate mycluster